# Verifcation of.. drives me crazy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, dex

Everytime I run my app (device or emulator is the same), even when not doing any change in code, I get for every method from my largest Activity this:

```
W/art: Verification of void com.xyz.abx.setCredit(boolean) took 343.200ms
```

As the app is quite big, this process takes a few minutes everytime and literally drivers me mad. The strange thing is that it doesn't do that for all the other smaller Activities.
I have

```
android:vmSafeMode="true"
```

in the Manifest as suggested in an SO thread, but to no avail.
I have read this thread

[Art: Verification of X took Y ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006954/art-verification-of-x-took-y-ms)
and read the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37006954/5180017) StackOverflow question? Also check this [official](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art) documentation.

Comment: Yes, this is the SO post I saw and the doc I read. The verification message comes up EVERYTIME I run the app and not only the first time as written in the thread

Comment: Okay. Please [edit] the question add these links and solutions you've tried. It's easier to understand the question

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually asked a question here... Are you wanting to figure out why verification is taking so long? Are you wanting to turn off verification? Increase the verification warning "timeout" so it doesn't complain about your class?

Comment: I want to turn it off. It takes up to 5 minutes everytime I start the app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Art: Verification of X took Y ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006954/art-verification-of-x-took-y-ms)